# Amazon Athena (Presto) SELECT statement to create (n^2 + n)/2 (th triangular number)

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I'm using Athena and trying to find a way to create a select statement that will return a sequence in the below format:

```
Numer
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
```

And so on, up to 200.
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combine [`sequence()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) with [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest):

```
SELECT n FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 5)) t(n)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(1, n)) x(y);
```

```
presto:default> SELECT n
             -> FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 5)) t(n)
             -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(1, n)) x(y);
 n
---
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 4
 4
 4
 4
 5
 5
 5
 5
 5
(15 rows)
```

(tested in Presto 326 but will work in Athena too)

Comment: @Byrdziu we greatly improved performance of `UNNEST` queries in Presto 316, but Athena is still based on Presto .172. If you're unnesting larger data sets, you may want to run latest the greatest (https://prestosql.io/download.html) or use Starburst's convenient Presto for AWS https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```sql
SELECT numbers FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES flatten(
            transform(
                sequence(1, 4),
                x -> repeat(x, cast(x AS INT))
            )
        )
    ) AS x (a) CROSS JOIN UNNEST(a) AS t (numbers)
);
```

it will return:

```
 numbers 
---------
       1 
       2 
       2 
       3 
       3 
       3 
       4 
       4 
       4 
       4 
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't seem to work on Athena. After changing 'INT' to integer it throws the following error:  Function repeat not registered

Comment: `repeat()` is a presto function. if it's not registered in Athena, you can use @piotr's beautiful answer :)